# Not able connect to PDB, Oracle 19C Linux RH7.7 ORA-01034, ORA-27101

Tags: linux, oracle, pdb

So I'm struggling with Oracle for almost 2 days and I gave up. I believe that I checked all solutions available at uncle google.

To summarize my issue:

1. I have deployed Oracle 19C on Linux RH 7.7. SID = orcl, PDBS = orclpdb and PDB
2. I can connect to Oracle instance from the host machine and a remote machine
3. I can do alter session set container = PDB; ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE PDB OPEN;

But when I try login to pdb via

-Sqlplus(localhost) - oracle/product/19/dbhome/bin/sqlplus system/password@pdb

-Impdp (localhost)

-Sqldeveloper (remote)
[image]

I received an error:

```
ERROR:ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 4376
Additional information: -1774770425
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

My environment looks like:

```
show pdbs;
    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
     2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO        
     3 ORCLPDB                        MOUNTED              
     4 PDB                            READ WRITE NO     

$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/oracle/product/19/dbhome
$ echo $ORACLE_SID
orcl
```

Listener:

```
cat /oracle/product/19/dbhome/network/admin/listener.ora
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /oracle/product/19/dbhome/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
  (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/product/19/dbhome)
  (SID_NAME = orcl)
)
(SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orclpdb)
  (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/product/19/dbhome)
  (SID_NAME = orclpdb)
)
(SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = pdb)
  (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/product/19/dbhome)
  (SID_NAME = pdb)
)
)

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.103.19.240)(PORT = 1521))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
)
```

Tnsnames:

```
cat /oracle/product/19/dbhome/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
ORCL=
(description=
(address_list=
 (address = (protocol = TCP)(host = 10.103.19.240)(port = 1521))
 )
(connect_data =
(service_name=orcl)
)
)
PDB=
(description=
(address_list=
 (address = (protocol = TCP)(host = 10.103.19.240)(port = 1521))
 )
(connect_data =
(service_name=pdb)
)
)
```

Based on **https://community.oracle.com/thread/2572501**

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
```

Listener status:

```
$ /oracle/product/19/dbhome/bin/lsnrctl start
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 15-SEP-2020 12:11:13

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /oracle/product/19/dbhome/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is /oracle/product/19/dbhome/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ies-phipdb-r77/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.103.19.240)(PORT=1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.103.19.240)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                15-SEP-2020 12:11:13
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /oracle/product/19/dbhome/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ies-phipdb-r77/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.103.19.240)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclpdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orclpdb", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "pdb", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

**Any ideas why it doesn't work? and how to make it works?**

Regards
Piotr

Comment: Maybe a daft question but -- is the relevant database instance actually running? Is the "status UNKNOWN" message a red flag?

Comment: @Varqina . Don't worry, we will help you. First of all, rename your listener.ora to listener.ora.1 and restart the listener. (without listener.ora, default settings are used) I don't like all the SID_NAMEs in there which are not SIDs. A database instance has only one sid - system identifier - and in your case it is 'orcl' . PDBs are exposed by service_name

Comment: @Bjarte Brandt Thank you for your comment. I did it and it said: "The listener supports no services The command completed successfully" . When I try to connect to orcl or pdb error ORA-12514 is alive.

Comment: @KevinBoone Thank you for your comment. I tried $ echo STARTUP | /oracle/product/19/dbhome/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba  and it returned:
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 16 09:59:01 2020Version 19.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
SQL> ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

It is your SID_LIST_LISTENER config in listener.ora

Having a list of pluggables in there as "SID" means the listener is offering out those names as if they were instances. This is why you get the "shared realm etc etc", because those *instances* do not exist (and hence are started).

A typical listener.ora might look like

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1519))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER19 =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\19)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\oracle\product\19\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
  )
```

where you can see the entries there are just to support host/port and external programs.  Each pluggable will happily register itself with the listener, which will then offer the pluggables out as *services*.

Comment: Hello @ConnorMcDonald. I did my listener.ora file based on the article http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_cdb_pdb_configuration_files.htm    How in your opinion it should look like? I mean my listener.ora file

Comment: like mine above. The services will automatically register with the listener. Some of the information on dba-oracle.com is out of date or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In my Vagrant/Virtualbox environment:

## rename listener.ora (use default settings)

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ mv /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora.1
```

## restart listener

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ lsnrctl stop; lsnrctl start; lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 16-SEP-2020 11:10:41

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
The command completed successfully

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 16-SEP-2020 11:10:41

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                16-SEP-2020 11:10:41
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 16-SEP-2020 11:10:41

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                16-SEP-2020 11:10:41
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

## there are no services exposed via the listener yet!

```
# A database background process is responsible for registration every 30 sec,
# but we can force service registration
[oracle@localhost ~]$ echo 'alter system register;' | sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 16 11:11:41 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL>
System altered.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
```

## oh yes! services are there

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 16-SEP-2020 11:12:12

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                16-SEP-2020 11:10:41
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 1 min. 30 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "+ASM_DATA" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "86b637b62fdf7a65e053f706e80a27ca.oradb3.private" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "af547de90c477ffee055000000000001.oradb3.private" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl.oradb3.private" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.oradb3.private" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdb1.oradb3.private" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

## my CDB is named: orcl.oradb3.private

```
# now, let's connect!
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus system/Welcome1@localhost:1521/orcl.oradb3.private

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 16 11:21:05 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Sep 16 2020 11:20:48 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> col name for a30
SQL> r
  1* select con_id, name from v$pdbs

    CON_ID NAME
---------- ------------------------------
         2 PDB$SEED
         3 PDB1
```

## my PDB is named: pdb1.oradb3.private

```
# now, let's connect!
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus system/Welcome1@localhost:1521/pdb1.oradb3.private

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 16 11:24:46 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Sep 16 2020 11:21:05 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0


SQL> sho con_id

CON_ID
------------------------------
3
SQL>
```

Make sure you can connect using EZConnect, thereafter alter your `tnsnames.ora` to reflect your exposed services.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replay and the time which you have spent on it.

It was solved by adding the suffix of FQDN to PDB name in Listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.

Also to connect remotely I needed to add this suffix too.